# How to detect if a browser has English spellcheck enabled?

Tags: browser-support, browser-detecting, detection, spelling, spellcheck

I'm building a language learning app and there are some input fields (using CKEditor 5) where users can input English text.

CKEditor 5 has spellcheck plugins, but I am trying to keep my website as lightweight as possible, so I am happy to rely on built-in browser spellchecking. I've been running usability tests of my site with users and it's working quite well for most people.

However, some users don't have English language spellcheck available (or toggled on) on their mobile phones, so I'd like to check if the user's phone has English spellchecking enabled, and if not, show a message with some links for setting up spellcheck on various devices.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317598/javascript-access-to-spell-checker-on-browsers) makes it pretty clear that there is no access via JS to override the browser spellcheck, but I don't want to override it-- I only want to know if English spellcheck is available, and if not, show a message.

Is there any way to do this, by media query or otherwise?